# Replace comma or whitespace with hyphen in same string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need PHP code to replace comma or whitespace with hyphen

For eg: 
  If `$value = 'home garden'` or `$value = 'home,garden'` ,

i need result as `home-garden`

I tried `$result = preg_replace('/\s+[\,]/', '-', trim($value));` , but no use..

Can someone explain it?

Comment: As you can imagine the regular expression is not what you're looking for. You *might* want to learn about [character classes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$result = preg_replace('/[ ,]+/', '-', trim($value));
```

Test:

```
$value = '  home  ,garden , gardener  ';
$result = preg_replace('/[ ,]+/', '-', trim($value));

echo $result;
//home-garden-gardener
```

Answer (score 12):

`$result = str_replace(array(',', ' '), '-', $value);`

Comment: no idea why others make such complex solutions, when this one is obviously the fastest and correct one :)

Comment: Why did you remove the trim at the end?

Comment: Yeah the trim should be left in, otherwise the whitespaces at the beginning/end (if any) will be turned into hyphens instead.

Comment: @Robin v. G. : Thnak u for ur reply.. Its working .. But if string contains multiple spaces or a comma followed by space, result gives two consecutive hyphen... How we can make this as single hyphen?

Answer (score 1):

```
    $stringAfter = str_replace(",", "-",$stringBefore);

    example:
    $stringBefore="abc,def,ghi";
    $stringAfter = str_replace(",", "-",$stringBefore);
    print $stringAfter;

    Output:
   `abc-def-ghi`
```